# Hagedorn transitions in 10 D and 11 D string/M-theories?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, string-theory, temperature

Are there [Hagedorn transitions](https://www.google.com/search?as_epq=Hagedorn+transition) in 10D superstrings and 11D M-theory?

Answer (score -1):

First, little string theory (LST) is a non-gravitational non-local theory in six spacetime dimensions, that can be obtained as an effective theory of NS5 branes in the limit in which gravity decouples.

If you use brane gas cosmology to M-theory degrees of freedom, M2 and M5 branes' intersections, you will get a 4 dimensional spacetime (instead of 6 spacetime dimensions).

One dimensional intersections in 11D is related to LST on NS5 branes. Now LSTs on a worldvolume of M5 branes wrapping a five dimensional torus, lead to a 3+1 dimensional spacetime. This is consostent with the gas approximation in the M-theory.

Now you are asking if there are Hagedorn transitions:

LST has a Hagedorn density of states at very high energies that which follows from the little string partition sum. LST undergoes a phase transition, above the Hagedorn transition similar to the case of fundamental strings in 10D.

Please see here:

https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/afad/6ce6145445da42316793ed72980e50d6ca0c.pdf

Comment: Why the downvote?